# Building Android for Nexus Player - which version to choose

Tags: android, android-source, nexus-player

I'm building Android for Nexus Player, and I'm not sure which *combo* to choose:

```
$ lunch

You're building on Linux

Lunch menu... pick a combo:
     1. aosp_arm-eng
     2. aosp_arm64-eng
     3. aosp_mips-eng
     4. aosp_mips64-eng
     5. aosp_x86-eng
     6. aosp_x86_64-eng
     7. aosp_deb-userdebug
     8. aosp_flo-userdebug
     9. full_fugu-userdebug
     10. aosp_fugu-userdebug
     11. aosp_grouper-userdebug
     12. aosp_tilapia-userdebug
     13. mini_emulator_arm64-userdebug
     14. m_e_arm-userdebug
     15. mini_emulator_mips-userdebug
     16. mini_emulator_x86_64-userdebug
     17. mini_emulator_x86-userdebug
     18. aosp_flounder-userdebug
     19. aosp_hammerhead-userdebug
     20. aosp_mako-userdebug
     21. aosp_shamu-userdebug
     22. aosp_manta-userdebug

Which would you like? [aosp_arm-eng]
```

The codename for Nexus Player is **fugu**, so I can choose either 9 or 10. But what's the difference between the two? Has anyone successfully flashed a Nexus Player using either of those? I can flash the device, but can't get it into the pairing mode afterwards. Thanks!